# enable_if with is_enum does not work

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

MCVE:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
bool func( typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<T>::value, T >::type &t, int x )
{
}

enum class Bar { a,b,c };

int main()
{
    Bar bar{Bar::a};
    func(bar, 1);
}
```

I expect `func(bar, 1);` to match my definition of `func` however g++ reports:

```
sfi.cc: In function 'int main()':
sfi.cc:13:17: error: no matching function for call to 'func(Bar&, int)'
      func(bar, 1);
                 ^
sfi.cc:13:17: note: candidate is:
sfi.cc:4:10: note: template<class T> bool func(typename std::enable_if<std::is_e
num<_Tp>::value, T>::type&, int)
     bool func( typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<T>::value, T >::type &t, int x )
          ^
sfi.cc:4:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
sfi.cc:13:17: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
      func(bar, 1);
                 ^
```

Why isn't this working and how do I fix it?

*Background:* This was an attempted solution to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762892/how-to-specialize-a-template-function-for-enum-and-specific-type)

Answer (score 11):

```
template<typename T>
bool func( typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<T>::value, T >::type &t, int x )
```

`T` is used above in a non-deduced context.  This means it won't deduct the `T`, as it (in the general case) requires reversing an arbitrary turing-complete transformation, which is impossible.

What `func` has is that the first argument is a `enum class Bar`, and the second is an `int`.  From this you expect it to deduce `T`.

While setting `T` to `enum class Bar` does solve the problem, C++ doesn't guess.  It pattern matches.

Suppose we had:

```
template<class T>
struct blah { using type=int; };
template<>
struct blah<int> { using type=double; };
```

then

```
template<class T>
bool func( typename blah<T>::type );
```

If someone passes a `int` to `func`, what type should be deduced for `T`?  This is a toy example: `foo<T>::type` can execute a Turing-complete algorithm to map `T` to the type in question.  Inverting that or even determining if the inverse is ambiguous, is not possible in the general case.  So C++ doesn't even try, even in the simple cases, as the edge between simple and complex gets fuzzy quickly.

To fix your problem:

```
template<class T,class=typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<T>::value >::type>
bool func( T &t, int x ) {
}
```

now `T` is used in a deduced context.  The SFINAE still occurs, but doesn't block template type deduction.

Or you can wait for C++1z concepts, which automate the above construct (basically).

---

Looking at the linked question, the easy way to solve your problem is with tag dispatching.

```
template<typename T> 
bool func(T &t, int x)
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

However I would like to have three different function bodies:

We have 3 cases:

- T being an enum
- T being unsigned char
- Everything else

so, dispatch:

```
namespace details {
  template<class T>
  bool func( T& t, int x, std::true_type /* is_enum */, std::false_type ) {
  }
  template<class T>
  bool func( T& t, int x, std::false_type, std::true_type /* unsigned char */ ) {
  }
  template<class T>
  bool func( T& t, int x, std::false_type, std::false_type ) {
    // neither
  }
}
template<class T>
bool func( T& t, int x ) {
  return details::func( t, x, std::is_enum<T>{}, std::is_same<unsigned char, T>{} );
}
```

now normal overload rules are used to pick between the 3 functions.  If you somehow have a type that is both `enum` and `unsigned char` (impossible), you get a compile-time error.

Answer (score 5):

You're using the template argument `T` in a non-deduced context.

From *§14.8.2.5/5 **[temp.deduct.type]***

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>   — The *nested-name-specifier* of a type that was specified using a *qualified-id*.
>   — ...

To fix the problem move the `enable_if` to a dummy template parameter

```
template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<T>::value, T >::type>
bool func( T &t, int x )
{
  // ...
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f099ec1a4a208d3)

---

Looking at the question you linked to, you're trying to switch between two definitions of `func` based on whether the first argument is an `enum`. In that case the above solution will not work because a default template argument is not part of the function template's signature, and you'll end up with multiple definition errors.

There are two different ways to fix that, use a dummy template parameter

```
template<typename T,
         typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<T>::value, int >::type* = nullptr>
bool func( T &t, int x )
{
  // ...
}
```

or use the `enable_if` expression in the return type

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<T>::value, bool >::type 
    func( T &t, int x )
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Right, I did get multiple definition errors when trying your first suggestion and couldn't understand why they were appearing, so thanks for explaining that also :)

Answer (score 2):

The errors you are seeing have to do with automatic type deduction than `enable_if` and `is_enum`.

The following works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
bool func( typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<T>::value, T >::type &t, int x )
{
   return true;
}

enum class Bar { a,b,c };

int main()
{
    Bar bar{Bar::a};
    std::cout << func<decltype(bar)>(bar, 1) << std::endl;
}
```

**Update**

As already discovered by the OP, use of `decltype` can be avoided by using a wrapper function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
bool func( typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<T>::value, T >::type &t, int x )
{
   return true;
}

template <typename T>
bool func2( T &t, int x )
{
   return func<T>(t,x);
}

enum class Bar { a,b,c };

int main()
{
    Bar bar{Bar::a};
    std::cout << func2(bar, 1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: OK, that's something. It seems to work with a wrapper too: `template<typename T> bool func2( T &t, int  x) { return func<T>(t, x); }`