# How to specialize a template function for enum, and specific type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I currently have a function:

```
template<typename T> 
bool func(T &t, int x)
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

However I would like to have three different function bodies:

1. `T` being an `enum`
2. `T` being `unsigned char`
3. Everything else

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762813/enable-if-with-is-enum-does-not-work) already but didn't get far.

What are the correct function declarations for these three cases to work?

---

The closest I have been able to come up with is Case 1 being:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<T>::value, bool >::type func( T &t, int x)
```

and Case 3 being:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< not std::is_enum<T>::value, bool >::type func( T &t, int x)
```

however I have not been able to make something work for Case 2 that compiles. As a workaround I have an `if` statement inside Case 3 to handle unsigned chars but that is not ideal.

Comment: *"however I have not been able to make something work for Case 2 that compiles"* how about a simple overload for `bool func( unsigned char t, int x )` ?

Comment: Why should all enums be treated differently from all other types? Enums do not have a set of common behaviour that distinguishes them from other types. Or is this just an academic exercise?

Comment: @PiotrS. I originally got a multiple definition error doing that, but didn't realize until just now that that is fixable by making it `inline bool func ( unsigned char t, int x );`

Comment: @Brian Case 3 of `func` uses `istream::operator>>` into `t` and this is not defined for enums. (and I want to do something fairly different for enums, not solvable just by overloading operator>>).

Answer (score 9):

Use tag dispatching:

```
namespace details {
  template<class T>
  bool func( T& t, int x, std::true_type /* is_enum */, std::false_type ) {
  }
  template<class T>
  bool func( T& t, int x, std::false_type, std::true_type /* unsigned char */ ) {
  }
  template<class T>
  bool func( T& t, int x, std::false_type, std::false_type ) {
    // neither
  }
}
template<class T>
bool func( T& t, int x ) {
  return details::func( t, x, std::is_enum<T>{}, std::is_same<unsigned char, T>{} );
}
```

Comment: that's probably a heck of a lot cleaner than mucking around with enable_if

Comment: Can't you also use [`std::is_unsigned<T>{}`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned)?

Comment: @0x49 why would that help?  I had 3 cases to deal with, that does not reliably distinguish between them.

Answer (score 2):

Turn out the comment about overload into answer:

```
// For enum
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, bool>::type
func(T& t, int x);

// for unsigned char
bool func(unsigned char& t, int x);

// for other
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value, bool>::type
func(T& t, int x);
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/UMWzbF)

An alternative is to use specialization for `unsigned char`:

```
// for other
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value, bool>::type
func(T& t, int x);

// specialization for unsigned char
template <>
bool func(unsigned char& t, int x);
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/B2QRpJ)